# addEventListener no agrega el evento al botón

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un botón con la clase btnEditRol en la cual por medio de Javascript le estoy asignando un evento para que me ejecute un Modal pero no me lo ejecuta. Al momento de verificar en la consola se puede ver que no le asigna al botón el evento.
Probé agregando directamente al botón onclick="fntEditRol();" para que me ejecute el evento que requiero llamar a través del botón y funciona correctamente pero no es lo adecuado ya que quiero que se llame desde javascript.

Este es el Modal

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFormRol" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header headerRegister">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="titleModal">Nuevo Rol</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-body">
              <form id="formRol" name="formRol">
                <input type="hidden" id="idRol" name="idRol" value="">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre del Rol" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Descripción</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion" name="txtDescripcion" rows="2" placeholder="Ingresa la descripción" required=""></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="exampleSelect1">Estado</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="listStatus" name="listStatus" required="">
                      <option value="1">Activo</option>
                      <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tile-footer">
              <button id="btnActionForm" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill me-2"></i><span id="btnText">Guardar</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" data-bs-dismiss="modal" ><i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill me-2"></i>Cancelar</a>
            </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el Javascript donde tengo la función fntEditRol agregandole el evento al botón.

```js
function openModal(){
    console.log("Llamando a OpenModal()");
    document.querySelector('#idRol').value ="";
    document.querySelector('.modal-header').classList.replace("headerUpdate", "headerRegister");
    document.querySelector('#btnActionForm').classList.replace("btn-info", "btn-primary");
    document.querySelector('#btnText').innerHTML ="Guardar";
    document.querySelector('#titleModal').innerHTML = "Nuevo Rol";
    document.querySelector('#formRol').reset();
    $('#modalFormRol').modal('show');
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("Evento 'load' detectado. Llamando a fntEditRol");
    fntEditRol();
    
}, false);

function fntEditRol(){
    var btnEditRol = document.querySelectorAll('.btnEditRol');
    btnEditRol.forEach(function(btnEditRol) {
        btnEditRol.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log("Evento 'load' detectado. Llamando a fntEditRol()");
            document.querySelector('#titleModal').innerHTML ="Actualizar Rol";
            document.querySelector('.modal-header').classList.replace("headerRegister", "headerUpdate");
            document.querySelector('#btnActionForm').classList.replace("btn-primary", "btn-info");
            document.querySelector('#btnText').innerHTML ="Actualizar";

            $('#modalFormRol').modal('show');
        });
    });
}
```

Esta es la tabla

```html
<?= headerAdmin($data);
getModal('modalRoles',$data);
?>
    <main class="app-content">
      <div class="app-title">
        <div>
          <h1><i class="bi bi-cone-striped"></i> <?= $data['page_tag'] ?>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="openModal();"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i>Nuevo</button>
          </h1>
          
        </div>
        <ul class="app-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><i class="bi bi-house-door fs-6"></i></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>roles"><?= $data['page_title'] ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tableRoles">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Descripcion</th>
                      <th>Estatus</th>
                      <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </main>
<?= footerAdmin($data); ?>
```

Este es el controlador donde tengo el botón.

```html
<?php

class Roles extends Controllers{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function Roles()
    {
        $data['page_id'] = 3;
        $data['page_tag'] = "Roles Usuario";
        $data['page_title'] = "rol_usuario";
        $data['page_name'] = "Roles Usuario <small>Tienda Virtual</small>";
        $this->views->getView($this,"roles",$data);
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $arrData= $this->model->selectRoles();

        for ($i=0; $i < count($arrData); $i++)
        {
            if ($arrData[$i]['status'] == 1)
            {
                $arrData[$i]['status'] = '<span class="me-1 badge bg-success">Activo</span>';
            
            }else{
                $arrData[$i]['status'] ='<span class="me-1 badge bg-danger">Inactivo</span>';
               
            }

            $arrData[$i]['options'] = '<div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btnPermisosRol" rl="'.$arrData[$i]['idrol'].'" title="Permisos"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditRol" rl="'.$arrData[$i]['idrol'].'" title="Editar"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnDelRol" rl="'.$arrData[$i]['idrol'].'" title="Eliminar"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                        </div>';

            
        }
        

       
        echo json_encode($arrData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        die();
    }
```

[image: Este es el botón con la clase btnEditRol]

[image: Este es el Javascript donde tengo la función fntEditRol agregandole el evento al botón.]

[image: Al verificar en la consola el botón no cuenta con el evento, ah no ser que le agregue onclick="fntEditRol();" en ese momento si aparece con evento el botón desde consola.]

[image: Aquí ya tiene el onclick y ejecuta perfectamente el evento de javascript.]

Comment: Hola. Pon el código como texto por favor, pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Listo ya subí el código

Comment: no veo el codigo php???

Comment: Agrega el HTML y el modal, al parecer tu lógica en JS esta mal, con eso te podremos ayudar mejor.

Comment: He probado las funciones, sin todo lo demás que hay dentro de ellas, porque ademas no tenemos el HTML completo, y son llamadas correctamente. Así como lo tienes, y quitando la llamada in line del botón: `onclick="fntEditRol();"` el código funciona. Si el model no se muestra esa ya es otra cosa. Revisa la consola de tu navegador en busca de errores, para ver por qué no funciona en tu caso.

Comment: La consola no me arroja ningún error. Puedes ver las imágenes adjuntas en la pregunta

Comment: deberias simplificar tu ejemplo, esto es irreproducible.

Comment: Lo que describes es el típico error que ocurre al intentar manipular/acceder a elementos que se generan de forma asíncrona. Por lo que se ve en el código compartido, los datos de la tabla no se están rellenando desde el PHP. Me imagino que los estás cargando con JavaScript una vez se ha cargado la página (algo muy común para hacer que la carga inicial sea más rápida). Si ese es el caso, estás intentando asociar el controlador del evento click a unos elementos que aún no existen en el DOM. Y si es así, la solución sería llamar a la función `fntEditRol` cuando se carguen los datos, no la página.

Comment: Puedes hacer una prueba rápida, añade esto a la funcion `fntEditRol`: `console.log("Numero de Elementos", btnEditRol.length);`. Estoy casi convencido de que el resultado será 0. Si estás cargando los datos de forma asíncrona, añade un `console.log("datos cargados")` a la función que carga los datos. Ese mensaje de consola se mostrará después del mensaje con el número de elementos. Si ese es el caso, tienes (al menos) un par de opciones: 1) llama a la función `fntEditRol` después de renderizar los datos; 2) usa eventos delegados.

Comment: Cuando generas HTML de forma dinámica es mucho más simple usar el atributo `onclick` que un `addEventListener`, en tu caso no veo beneficio alguno en utilizar este último